# Improving sql query performance on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, entity-attribute-value

I have an sql query with ten unions of queries in fact. So I want to avoid these unions because of resource consuming. In this example I just show one union.

```sql
  SELECT *
    FROM (  SELECT sv.SubmissionId,
                   sv1.FieldValue Etablissement,
                   sv2.FieldValue Nom,
                   sv3.FieldValue Prenom,
                   sv4.FieldValue Fonction,
                   sv5.FieldValue Identification,
                   sv6.FieldValue NomFormation,
                   ''         Signature
              FROM dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv
                   INNER JOIN dfmna_rsform_submissions sub
                       ON sv.SubmissionId = sub.SubmissionId
                   LEFT JOIN dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv1
                       ON sv.SubmissionId = sv1.SubmissionId
                      AND sv1.FieldName = 'NomEtablissement-Individuelle'
                   LEFT JOIN dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv2
                       ON sv.SubmissionId = sv2.SubmissionId
                      AND sv2.FieldName = 'Nom-Individuelle'
                   LEFT JOIN dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv3
                       ON sv.SubmissionId = sv3.SubmissionId
                      AND sv3.FieldName = 'Prenom-Individuelle'
                   LEFT JOIN dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv4
                       ON sv.SubmissionId = sv4.SubmissionId
                      AND sv4.FieldName = 'Fonction-Individuelle'
                   LEFT JOIN dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv5
                       ON sv.SubmissionId = sv5.SubmissionId
                      AND sv5.FieldName = 'NumAdelirpps-Individuelle'
                   LEFT JOIN dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv6
                       ON sv.SubmissionId = sv6.SubmissionId
                      AND sv6.FieldName = 'Nom-Formation'
             WHERE sv.FormId = 4
               AND sub.confirmed = 1
          GROUP BY sv.SubmissionId
          UNION ALL
            SELECT sv.SubmissionId,
                   sv1.FieldValue Etablissement,
                   sv2.FieldValue Nom,
                   sv3.FieldValue Prenom,
                   sv4.FieldValue Fonction,
                   sv5.FieldValue Identification,
                   sv6.FieldValue NomFormation,
                   ''         Signature
              FROM dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv
                   INNER JOIN dfmna_rsform_submissions sub
                       ON sv.SubmissionId = sub.SubmissionId
                   LEFT JOIN dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv1
                       ON sv.SubmissionId = sv1.SubmissionId
                      AND sv1.FieldName = 'NomEtablissement-Continue'
                   LEFT JOIN dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv2
                       ON sv.SubmissionId = sv2.SubmissionId
                      AND sv2.FieldName = 'Stg-Nom-Continue'
                   LEFT JOIN dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv3
                       ON sv.SubmissionId = sv3.SubmissionId
                      AND sv3.FieldName = 'Stg-Prenom-Continue'
                   LEFT JOIN dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv4
                       ON sv.SubmissionId = sv4.SubmissionId
                      AND sv4.FieldName = 'Stg-Fonction-Continue'
                   LEFT JOIN dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv5
                       ON sv.SubmissionId = sv5.SubmissionId
                      AND sv5.FieldName = 'Stg-NumAdelirpps-Continue'
                   LEFT JOIN dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv6
                       ON sv.SubmissionId = sv6.SubmissionId
                      AND sv6.FieldName = 'Nom-Formation'
             WHERE sv.FormId = 4
               AND sub.confirmed = 1
          GROUP BY sv.SubmissionId) t
   WHERE t.Nom <> ''
     AND t.NomFormation = 'my_criteria'
ORDER BY t.Nom;
```

So I want the same output but I want an other way to write this query without doing union. Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure you could merge the join critieria from each, e.g. `LEFT JOIN dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv1
                       ON sv.SubmissionId = sv1.SubmissionId
                      AND sv1.FieldName IN ('NomEtablissement-Individuelle', 'NomEtablissement-Continue')`. Repeat this idea for the other joins. Since everything else about the union-ed queries is identical, this should mean you only need one query and can get rid of the union. Try it, anyway

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thanks

Comment: MySQL gives you two tools to determine bottlenecks. First tool is `EXPLAIN`. It tells you what MySQL does with tables and how the optimizer thinks it should proceed to find your data. Second tool is `profiler`. It tells you, in detail, what MySQL did with files, CPU, network and operating system related to resource utilization. You didn't use either of the tools, and I'm pretty sure that while you were creating this question - StackOverflow suggested similar questions, which contain the info about mentioned two tools. You can't start optimizing if you don't know where the bottleneck is.

Answer (score 0):

you could rewrite it as

```
SELECT sv.SubmissionId,
sv.FieldValue,
''         Signature
FROM dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv INNER JOIN dfmna_rsform_submissions sub  ON sv.SubmissionId = sub.SubmissionId 
WHERE
sv.FieldName in ('NomEtablissement-Individuelle', 'Nom-Individuelle', 'Prenom-Individuelle', 'Fonction-Individuelle', 'NumAdelirpps-Individuelle', 'Nom-Formation')
AND sv.FormId = 4
AND sub.confirmed = 1
GROUP BY sv.SubmissionId
```

Comment: this won't work... where are sv2, sv3, sv4 etc in your code? The aliases don't exist in any more. Your suggestion changes the meaning and the result of the query

Comment: did u try this in the first place??  u have not used sv2, sv3, sv4 .... anywhere in the query. u should get the same result i hope.

Comment: I'm not the person who asked the question, so I can't try it. But it seems obvious to me that in a `SELECT` you cannot reference table aliases which don't exist in the `FROM` clause. The query will not compile.

Comment: Really sorry. i did not notice the err. querying a table self referencing itself many times will be extremely slow. This is what i wanted to share.

Comment: Downvote removed since it now compiles I think. However I don't think it will produce the same result as the original query, so it may not be useful. I can't run it so I'll leave it to the OP to comment on that. I think he is looking for some form of pivot query.

Comment: No solution works so I create a new table in which I store results of each statement. Then I only do a select statement on this new table. I just create all of this inside a stored procedure except table creation. It works better than original query. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the ugly world of EAV (entity-attribute-value) schemas.  (I added a tag so you can find lots more Q&A about it.)

```
   LEFT JOIN dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv4
                   ON sv.SubmissionId = sv4.SubmissionId
                  AND sv4.FieldName = 'Fonction-Individuelle'
```

The table `dfmna_rsform_submission_values` needs

```
PRIMARY KEY(SubmissionId, FieldName)
```

It probably has no need for an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

My suggested PK will help performance *some*.  But EAV is intrinsically a problem.

Another issue...  Did you really mean `LEFT`?  That implies that the attribute is optional.

```
         WHERE sv.FormId = 4
           AND sub.confirmed = 1
```

Since an `INDEX` cannot span two tables, this is hard to optimize.  Would it be reasonable to move one of those columns into the other table?

```
      GROUP BY sv.SubmissionId
```

is possibly 'wrong'  Look up `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

```
WHERE t.Nom <> ''
  AND t.NomFormation = 'my_criteria'
```

has you gathering lots of rows, only to later filter out some of them.  Fold those into the inner `SELECTs`.

Once you have done all of that, let's make another pass.  But please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  There will probably be a composite index needed to help with `NomFormation = 'my_criteria'`.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative... and I hate field-related extended record values, but hey if that's what you have, so be it. I would actually adjust this query to join for each required component as you had for the "sub" Confirmed = 1, no problem.  Then I would add your "dfmna_rsform_submission_values" ALSO as an INNER JOIN on the 'Nom-Formation' AND the VALUE equal to whatever your criteria was.

If the submission does not qualify that, who cares, skip any record and you are only left with those pre-qualified.

THEN I would do a SINGLE left-join to the "dfmna_rsform_submission_values" once left-joined on the Submission ID regardless of extra fields.

By applying a MAX( case/when ) on the individual field values you are looking for, it will only return that description for that column representation.

Doing a Group By on the submission will return one record per submission.

Just an alternative..

```
SELECT 
      sv.SubmissionId,
      max( case when sv1.FieldName IN ( 'NomEtablissement-Individuelle', 'NomEtablissement-Continue' )
                then sv1.FieldValue else '' end ) Etablissement,
      max( case when sv1.FieldName IN ( 'Nom-Individuelle', 'Stg-Nom-Continue' )
                then sv1.FieldValue else '' end ) Nom,
      max( case when sv1.FieldName IN ( 'Prenom-Individuelle', 'Stg-Prenom-Continue' )
                then sv1.FieldValue else '' end ) Prenom,
      max( case when sv1.FieldName IN ( 'Fonction-Individuelle', 'Stg-Fonction-Continue' )
                then sv1.FieldValue else '' end ) Fonction,
      max( case when sv1.FieldName IN ( 'NumAdelirpps-Individuelle', 'Stg-NumAdelirpps-Continue' )
                then sv1.FieldValue else '' end ) Identification,
      max( case when sv1.FieldName = 'Nom-Formation'
                then sv1.FieldValue else '' end ) NomFormation,
      max( '' ) Signature
   FROM 
      dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv
         INNER JOIN dfmna_rsform_submissions sub
            ON sv.SubmissionId = sub.SubmissionId
           AND sub.confirmed = 1

         INNER JOIN dfmna_rsform_submission_values svRequired
            ON sv.SubmissionId = svRequired.SubmissionId
            AND svRequired.FieldName = 'Nom-Formation'
            AND svRequired.FieldValue = 'my_criteria'

         LEFT JOIN dfmna_rsform_submission_values sv1
            ON sv.SubmissionId = sv1.SubmissionId
   WHERE 
      sv.FormId = 4
   GROUP BY 
      sv.SubmissionId
   HAVING
      max( case when sv1.FieldName IN ( 'Nom-Individuelle', 'Stg-Nom-Continue' )
                then sv1.FieldValue else '' end ) <> ''      
   ORDER BY 
      max( case when sv1.FieldName IN ( 'Nom-Individuelle', 'Stg-Nom-Continue' )
                then sv1.FieldValue else '' end )
```